# How to know if a port is blocked between host and guest

Tags: port

I have a Kibana installed on CentOS in VMWare, starts with no issue on 5602, and accessible from VMWare, but it doesn't allow me to access it through my VM host which is my desktop, indeed I see error:

```
Unable to connect

Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at 192.168.211.251:5602.
```

192.168.211.251 is the IP address of the CentOS guest.

It would be really appreciated if someone can help me sort it out.

I checked `sudo iptables -xvn -L | grep 5602` and `sudo iptables -xvn -L | grep 5601`, both show nothing.

> `netstat -tulnp | grep 5601` shows two entries, one from 127.0.0.1 and
>   the other from 192.168.211.251 (the host) - this is correct.
>
> `netstat -tulnp | grep 5602` shows only one entry from 127.0.0.1

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you add the ports to firewall-cmd?

Comment: No I do not, I didn't do anything to 5601 either and 5601 is accessible